# Note related list on Account does not show any input

Tags: standard-objects, notes

I try to find the object for the Note related list on Account (NOT the notes and attachments list!). We have input in Notes, but when I query on the standard object Note no data is shown. Where can I access Notes programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find those records in [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) object. So you will have to do a SOQL on `ContentNote` and the link between `ContentNote` and any related record is stored in the `ContentDocumentLink`.

You can go through the [schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm)  of [ContentNote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm) for further help on this topic.

[image]

Comment: I have inserted a test Note and queried on "ContentNotification" (ContentNote is not available) and I do not get any results.

Comment: What is the error you are getting when querying on `ContentNote` ?

Comment: No, it did not return any records.

Comment: The record does show in the object "Notes" though, but also the query on the standard object Note gives no result.

Comment: I do not even see Note as an object in the Object Manager.

Comment: Ok, I see where the problem lies. You can query and access ContentNote only via the console and programmatically. The object does not show in the Workbench nor in the Object Manager.

Comment: This answer helps: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104408/how-can-i-create-an-account-note-or-contact-note-via-api-that-is-visible-in-sale

Comment: @user40501 It does show up in Workbench. Anyhow good that you have got that working.

Comment: Correction: It shows up in the Enterprise Org also in the workbench, but not in the Developer Org.